# Palo Alto PA-3250 default credentials at PA-HDF login prompt (after factory reset)

Tags: palo-alto

I factory-reset a PAN-PA-3250 and can't login.  I tried admin / admin, but that didn't work.

What is the default password at the PA-HDF prompt?

```
Starting NFS services:  [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd: [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon: [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd: [  OK  ]
Starting PAN Software: [   38.034110] pan_crash_save: probe of 0-0056 failed
 with error -22
* * * * *  FIPS-CC Plugin Self-Tests Stage-2 begins * * * * *
* * * * *  FIPS-CC Plugin Self-Tests Stage-2 passed * * * * *
[  OK  ]

PA-HDF login:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

I opened a Palo Alto support case.  According to Palo Alto tech-support, you have to:
A) Connect an RJ45 serial cable to the firewall's console port at 9600-8N1.  Typical light-blue Cisco RJ45 serial console cables seem to work.
B) Repeatedly hit Enter for "a few minutes"
C) Ignore the console's "PA-HDF login:" prompt
D) Wait until all the boot-console-chatter ceases.
E) Login with admin / admin.

---

### Discussion

I'm struggling to understand Palo Alto's decision to print a login prompt but require users to ignore it.  Why show a login prompt at all?

When I tried recovering a troubled Palo Alto PA-3250 firewall with file system errors, the system was shutting down before I could complete the sequence.

The Palo Alto support engineer said that he thinks there is an enhancement request to improve system recovery under these conditions.

---

### Example serial console login

Console output from when I successfully logged-in the firewall console with admin / admin.  Note that admin / admin was rejected before all console-boot-output was completed (ref -> "pci_dma_host: platform=90099").

Some text was obfuscated below.

```
Starting Networking: [  OK  ]
Starting system logger: [  OK  ]
Starting kernel logger: [  OK  ]
Starting irqbalance: [  OK  ]
Starting rpcbind: [  OK  ]
Starting pan_hardserver: [  OK  ]
[  OK  ]
Skipping sshd: starting with PAN system processes
Starting xinetd: [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]
Starting NFS services:  [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd: [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon: [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd: [  OK  ]
Starting PAN Software: [  OK  ]
PA-3250 login: admin
Password:
Login incorrect                <---- That was the correct password
pcic driver exiting
pci_dma_host: platform=90099   <----- Wait for this on the console
PA-3250 login:                 <------ Now you can login
PA-3250 login: admin
Password:
Last login: Fri May 15 08:40:46 on ttyS0
Enter old password :
Enter new password :
Confirm password   :
Default password can not be used for admin user
```